# Nikon D5100 sets wrong image height and width metadata

Tags: java, windows, image, ubuntu

I programmed a JAVA-programme to resize my pictures by following [this guide](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/). It works well, but I recognized a problem with vertical pictures. After resizing them, they are rotated to the left.

I spend a little bit of time to find the error. The problem seems to be my camera Nikon D5100. I use Ubuntu 13.04 and if I view the picture before I resize it, it is vertical. But if I view the image properties, the width and the height are switched (see link example).

[Before resizing](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3540/2ycgi8ni_png.htm)

So here lies the problem. There are some other funny things about that problem:

1. If I rotate the picture before resizing and rotate it back the height and the width are correct (or even if I just open the picture with gimp and export it, the width and height are correct).
2. I copied the picture to a Windows PC and there the properties are correct, but I still have the same problem if I run my programme there.
3. I reckognized the same behavior with the camera Pentax K-30.

Could you guess a solution for the problem (other than firmware update?), so that my programme works for all pictures correctly?

Here my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/*
 * @author Jan Schlenker
 * Resizes all images of a given directory
 */
public class ImageResizer { 
public static void main(String [] args){
    if(args.length != 2){
    System.out.println("Usage:   java ImageResizer <comma-seperated-image-type-list> <scale>\n" +
               "Example: java ImageResizer JPG,JPEG,DNG 0.5");
    return;
    }
    final String[] imageTypes = args[0].split(",");
    final double scale = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
    final File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    final File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if(files != null){
    for(final File file : files){
        if(file.isDirectory()){
        continue;
        }
        else{
        for(final String imageType : imageTypes){
            int lastDotIndex = file.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
            String compare = file.getName().substring(lastDotIndex + 1);
            if(imageType.equals(compare)){
            try{
                // Resize image
                System.out.println("Resize image: " + file.getName());
                BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(file);
                int type = originalImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();
                int newWidth = (int) (scale * originalImage.getWidth());
                int newHeight = (int) (scale * originalImage.getHeight());
                BufferedImage resizeImageHint = resizeImageWithHint(originalImage, type, newWidth, newHeight);

                ImageIO.write(resizeImageHint, imageType, new File(dir + File.separator + "Small_" + file.getName())); 

                // Delete original image
                file.delete();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}

private static BufferedImage resizeImageWithHint(BufferedImage originalImage, int type, int newWidth, int newHeight){
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
    g.dispose();    
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    return resizedImage;
}   
}
```